# Cokernel of chain map is complex of cokernels.

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

$\newcommand{\coker}{\text{coker}}$
$\newcommand{\Ima}{\text{Im}}$
I've started to learn some homological algebra and have been struggling with verifying that if $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category then the category of chain-complexes in $\mathcal{A}$ is also an abelian category. In particular, showing if $f_\bullet:A_\bullet \to B_\bullet$ is a chain map then $\coker (f_\bullet) = \dots \to \coker f_{n+1} \to \coker f_n \to \dots$..

The diagram I had in mind was:

[image]

Where $\pi_n:B_n \to B_n/\Ima(f_n)$ are natural projection, and I'd like to fill in the maps $\partial_n$ on the bottom row.

There's the obvious guess that you would induce the map $\tilde{d_n^B}: B_m/\Ima f_n \to B_{n-1}$ and then project onto $\coker f_{n-1}$, but to have the induced map I would need that $\Ima f_n \subseteq \ker d_n^B$, and I can't seem to conclude that's the case. I know everything in sight commutes, but $d_n^B \circ f_n = 0$ even seems like perhaps a wrong condition to me, because by commutativity of the square that would mean $f_{n-1} \circ d_n^A = 0$.

I know that if I take the composites $d_n^B \circ f_n \circ d_{n+1}^A = d_n^B \circ d_{n+1}^B \circ f_{n-1} = 0$ since $d^2 = 0$ on a chain complex, but then I'm left with $d_n^B \circ f_n \circ d_{n+1}^A = 0$, and $f_n \circ d_{n+1}^A$ wouldn't correspond to the image of $f_n$.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure the fact is straightforward I'm just not seeing it. Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:** Just in case someone comes across this but would prefer the language of $R$-modules (as I did), the differential in the cokernel complex is just induced by the factor isomorphism theorem, I was just going about it wrong:

The map $\pi \circ d_n^B:B_n \to \coker f_{n-1}$ will factor through $\coker f_n$ if and only if $\Ima f_n \subseteq \ker (\pi \circ d_n^B)$ but note that this kernel is $(d_n^B)^{-1}(\Ima f_{n-1})$ and so this is equivalent to requiring $d_n^B \circ \Ima f_n \subseteq \Ima f_{n-1}$ which is obvious from the commutativity of the top square. Therefore set $\partial_n$ to be the unique map factoring the composite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not only part of a proof that $\mathsf{Ch}(\mathscr{A})$ is Abelian (by in particular showing it has all cokernels) but it is part of a proof that the evaluation functors $e_n:\mathsf{Ch}(\mathscr{A})\to\mathscr{A}$ are exact (by preserving all cokernels).

We are given the zero complex as a clear zero object. It is clear a map of chain complexes is zero (by definition, factors through the zero object) if and only if every single component is zero. Given $f:A_\bullet\to B_\bullet$, $g:B_\bullet\to C_\bullet$, $gf$ is then zero if and only if $g_nf_n$ is zero for all $n$. That is to say, if and only if $g_n$ factors through $\operatorname{coker}f_n$ for every $n$.

There are then two things to check: firstly, that there is a sensible notion of differential making $\operatorname{Cok}_\bullet f$ a chain complex such that $\operatorname{coker}f:B_\bullet\to\operatorname{Cok}_\bullet f$ is a chain map, secondly that the induced map $\operatorname{Cok}_\bullet f\to C_\bullet$ which factors $g$ is a genuine chain map.

Let's sort out the first one. As: $$0=\operatorname{coker}f_{n-1}\circ f_{n-1}\circ\partial_n=\operatorname{coker}f_{n-1}\circ\partial_n\circ f_n$$It follows there exists a unique factorisation $\operatorname{coker}f_{n-1}\circ\partial_n=k\circ\operatorname{coker}f_n$. Let's make the $n$th differential for $\operatorname{Cok}_\bullet f$ the arrow $k$. Then, so long as this satisfies the $\partial^2=0$ property, we'd get a chain complex that by construction makes $\operatorname{coker}f$ a chain map. But this thing squaring to zero is straightforward, since when you precompose with $\operatorname{coker}f_{n+1}$ you see: $$k_n\circ k_{n+1}\circ\operatorname{coker}f_{n+1}=\partial_n\circ\operatorname{coker}f_n\circ\partial_{n+1}=\operatorname{coker}f_{n-1}\circ\partial_n\circ\partial_{n+1}=0$$And as this is an epimorphism we can remove the cokernel from the left hand side and deduce $k_n\circ k_{n+1}=0$ for all $n$.

Now for the second part.

Say $g_n=h_n\circ\operatorname{coker}f_n$ for each $n$. $$\begin{align}h_{n-1}\circ\partial_n\circ\operatorname{coker}f_n&=h_{n-1}\circ\operatorname{coker}f_{n-1}\circ\partial_{n-1}\\&=g_{n-1}\circ\partial_n\\&=\partial_n\circ g_n\\&=\partial_n\circ h_n\circ\operatorname{coker}f_n\end{align}$$Ok. By the universal property of cokernels (well, the uniqueness) we know they are epimorphisms; I can therefore remove $\operatorname{coker}f_n$ from both sides of the above (cancellation doesn't mean it has a right inverse!) and conclude $h_{n-1}\circ\partial_n=\partial_n\circ h_n$. So, $h_\bullet:\operatorname{Cok}_\bullet f\to C_\bullet$ is a chain map and it is unique because $g=hf$ iff. $g_n=h_nf_n$ for all $n$ (by definition) and each $h_n$ is unique in this respect.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Isn't my question more basic than this? If I understand the response, I'm stuck on the "sensible notion of differential" making $\operatorname{Cok}_\bullet(f)$ a chain complex? I.e for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ I can't seem to land the differentials $\partial_n: \operatorname{Cok}f_{n+1} \to \operatorname{Cok} f_n$? Also I guess your map $\operatorname{coker} f:B_\bullet \to \operatorname{Cok}_\bullet f$ is just going to be projection $B_n \to B_n/\operatorname{Im}f_n$?

Comment: @IrvingRabin My map $\operatorname{coker}f$ is the map whose every $n$th component is just $\operatorname{coker}f_n$. You can think about it as $B_n/\mathrm{Im}(f_n)$ if you like but you don't have to (and cokernels logically come first anyway; the first isomorphism theorem and image quotient stuff comes later). I've elaborated on the first part of the 'two steps' now

Comment: Thank you @FShrike. I neglected to mention that for my purposes I've been thinking of a (small) abelian category as just a subcategory of the category of $R$-modules via the Freyd-Mitchell embedding, and that's why I was thinking in normal algebra language rather than categorically.

Comment: Freyd mitchell doesn't do everything for us, is subtle to use in an accurate way and it's good imo to develop as much of the theory as possible (in fact, essentially all of it!) without using it. Especially for basic stuff like this

Comment: I thought I understood but where is the factorization $k$ coming from?

Comment: @IrvingRabin We saw that $(\operatorname{coker}(f_{n-1})\circ\partial_n)\circ f_n=0$. By the universal property of cokernel, any arrow $h$ with $h\circ f_n=0$ factors uniquely through some uniquely defined $k$ to the cokernel of $f_n$. In particular for us, by taking $h:=\operatorname{coker}(f_{n-1})\circ\partial_n$, we get a $k$ and call this “$k$” our differential $\partial_n$ for the cokernel complex.